# diverging implicit expansion for type scala.math.Ordering

Tags: list, scala, sorting, collections, scalaz

I'm sorry for this question but I haven't been able to get an answer from the previous questions.
I have a Scala class

```
case class Problem (
  ref:          Ref,
  v1:      Option[String],
  v2:     Option[Int],
  v3:  Option[Int]
) extends Ordered[Problem] {
   def v = ref.v
   def compare(other: Problem) = {
    import scalaz._
    import Scalaz._

    val v1Comp = ( v1 |@| other.v1 ) { case (r1, r2) => r1.compare(r2)}
    val v2Comp = ( v2 |@| other.2 ) { case (sr1, sr2) => sr1.compare(sr2)}
    val v3Comp = Some( v3.compare(other.v3) )
    (v1Comp, v2Comp, v3Comp) match {
      case (Some(v),_,_,_) if v!=0 => v
      case (_,Some(v),_,_) if v!=0 => v
      case (_,_,Some(v),_) if v!=0 => v
      case _                       => ref.v.compare(other.ref.v)
    }
  }
}
```

Now in another class I have a statement like:-

```
val probList = List(problem1, problem2).sorted
```

But is throws compile time issue:-

```
diverging implicit expansion for type Option[package.Problem] => Comparable[Option[package.Problem]]
```

when calling the sorted method.

I do not understand one more thing is that the same code works fine for Scala 2.10.x but upgrading it to 2.11.x is causing this issue.

Any help or guidance will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

**Note**:- the names of class and variable is slightly changed but the structure remains exact same

Comment: What is the version of Scalaz you're using? What is `Ref`? `r1`, `r2` are `String`s, so `r1.compare(r2)` is `scala.collection.immutable.StringLike#compare`, `sr1`, `sr2` are `Int`s, so `sr1.compare(sr2)` is `scala.runtime.OrderedProxy#compare`, but `v3`, `other.v3` are `Option[Int]`, what is `v3.compare(other.v3)`? It doesn't compile with `value compare is not a member of Option[Int]`. Why did you tag `apache-spark`?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi Dmytro, Ref is another case class which has v, v1, v2 and v3 already with some other properties. It's a prod running code written by someone else but I have to upgrade the Scala version and I'm getting issues at this point. Tagging Spark was just to give every detail. This is a spark project and RDD is what this deal with. Language is Scala.

Comment: *"Ref is another case class which has v, v1, v2 and v3 already with some other properties"* What other properties? What is the type of `v` in `Ref`? You haven't answered what version of Scalaz you're using. The problem is that you do not provide enough information to reproduce the behavior you observe. You said this compiled in 2.10. Well, it doesn't for me https://scastie.scala-lang.org/K16bXqd5RWK8kbuquDIjuw Please provide also your imports and signifact part of build file (build.sbt or pom.xml etc.). Please provide minimal reproducible code so that we can reproduce behavior you described.

Comment: If the code compiled for you in 2.10 but doesn't compile in 2.11 have you tried to clean and rebuild your project? For example with sbt `sbt clean compile`.

Comment: yes, I tried sbt clean compile. type of v in Ref is also Int. Scalaz version is 2.7.1

Comment: Scalaz version hardly can be 2.7.1. At least for Scala 2.10 it hardly can be. For Scala 2.10.x Scalaz starts from 6.0.3 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalaz/scalaz-core Current version of Scalaz is 7.3.2. So either Scala version is not 2.10 or Scalaz version is not 2.7.1. Please write your dependencies from build file. If we replace type of `v` with `Int` the code still doesn't compile in Scala 2.10.7 + Scalaz 7.2.30 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/w6bbY3DFQXOrdW0bjUTmjQ

Comment: Scalaz had version 2.x more that 10 years ago in 2009 while Scala had version 2.7 https://web.archive.org/web/20090122225508/http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/ https://github.com/scala/scala/releases?after=v2.10.0-M1 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_(programming_language)#Versions

Comment: *"the names of class and variable is slightly changed but the structure remains exact same"* Is it possible that duing this rewriting your code you actually accidentally broke it? I'm asking because you said that the code compiled in 2.10 but at Scastie the code doesn't compile in 2.10. Or maybe I incorrectly guessed missed places.

Comment: Regarding the structure change, I made sure that nothing changed except to the names of variables. I crossed checked that already. And sorry for the type in previous comment, the scalaz version being used in 7.1.0 If required, I can share my build.sbt as well but actually in the part of library dependencies, there are multiple internal imports. The main aim was to migrate this project from Spark V1.6 to Spark V2.1 hence all the scala and other dependencies had to be changed too

Comment: *"I made sure that nothing changed except to the names of variables."* Why then doesn't the code compile in 2.10 while you said that it compiled in 2.10? https://scastie.scala-lang.org/vOSsCHz0ScmVX5PGpF6wyQ (Scala 2.10.7 + Scalaz 7.1.0)

Comment: Not very sure, if required further to deep dive I can share the build.sbt file. Else if possible could you help me with the correct implementation? With the sample of code you may have idea of the requirement. Could you please guide me with that?

Answer (score 0):

I guess correct is

```
case class Ref(
                v: Int
              )

case class Problem(
                    ref: Ref,
                    v1: Option[String],
                    v2: Option[Int],
                    v3: Option[Int]
                  ) extends Ordered[Problem] {
  def v = ref.v

  def compare(other: Problem) = {
    import scalaz._
    import Scalaz._

    val v1Comp = (v1 |@| other.v1) { case (r1, r2) => r1.compare(r2) }
    val v2Comp = (v2 |@| other.v2) { case (r1, r2) => r1.compare(r2) }
    val v3Comp = (v3 |@| other.v3) { case (r1, r2) => r1.compare(r2) }
    (v1Comp, v2Comp, v3Comp) match {
      case (Some(v), _, _) if v != 0 => v
      case (_, Some(v), _) if v != 0 => v
      case (_, _, Some(v)) if v != 0 => v
      case _ => ref.v.compare(other.ref.v)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Umm I'm sorry but aren't these two same?

Comment: @ShashwatSharma Surely they are not. Your original code didn't compile https://scastie.scala-lang.org/2wtusQTLTa60afqE7n0H5w This code does https://scastie.scala-lang.org/xFMPfXXxRUmCUZfVofgGUg Can you see the difference now?

Comment: @ShashwatSharma I modified the definition of `v3Comp` in order to fix type mismatch and patterns in the cases of pattern matching now have 3 positions rather than 4.